# How do I view contents of initramfs.img in Debian-based distributions?

Tags: debian, filesystems, boot, initramfs, compression

I often have open questions regarding the booting of a machine with GNU/Linux installed. In such cases, it could be helpful to view which files are present in the initramfs image. I have googled for a bit, and some tutorials claim to achieve it (often using some kind of decompressing routine), but none of the tutorials I have found worked for my particular distribution of GNU/Linux. It makes me think that the answer might be distribution and kernel dependent.

So, what's the easiest way to find out the contents of initramfs.img files for Debian-based distributions of GNU/Linux?

Comment: The file command will tell you what format the file is in and each format has a utility that will let you unpack mount or decompress it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `lsinitramfs`. For example,

```
sudo lsinitramfs "/boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r)"
```

will list the contents of the initramfs matching the currently-running kernel (assuming you’re using a Debian-packaged kernel).

If you want to extract files from an initramfs, check out `unmkinitramfs`.

Comment: For RedHat-Fedora at least, the command is `lsinitrd`.